# Ошибка переполнение стека при addTextChangedListener

Tags: java, android

У меня есть `EditText` с маской даты. И при вызове слушателя крашится приложение.

**Объявление `Arraylist` для `EditText`ов:**

```
ArrayList<EditText> ListDocumentExpiry = new ArrayList<>();
```

**В цикле:**

```
ListBirthDate.get(i).addTextChangedListener(Mask.insert("##.##.####", ListBirthDate.get(i)));
```

**Класс маски:**

```
public abstract class Mask {
public static String unmask(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("[.]", "").replaceAll("[-]", "")
            .replaceAll("[/]", "").replaceAll("[(]", "")
            .replaceAll("[)]", "");
}

public static TextWatcher insert(final String mask, final EditText ediTxt) {
    return new TextWatcher() {
        boolean isUpdating;
        String old = "";
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,int count) {
            String str = Mask.unmask(s.toString());
            String mascara = "";
            if (isUpdating) {
                old = str;
                isUpdating = false;
                return;
            }
            int i = 0;
            for (char m : mask.toCharArray()) {
                if (m != '#' && str.length() > old.length()) {
                    mascara += m;
                    continue;
                }
                try {
                    mascara += str.charAt(i);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    break;
                }
                i++;
            }
            isUpdating = true;
            ediTxt.setText(mascara);
            ediTxt.setSelection(mascara.length());
        }
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            ediTxt.setError(null);
        }
    };
  }
}
```

**Вот сама ошибка:**

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                         java.lang.StackOverflowError
                                                             at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.checkRange(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1013)
                                                             at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.getChars(SpannableStringBuilder.java:913)
                                                             at android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:70)
                                                             at android.text.method.ReplacementTransformationMethod$ReplacementCharSequence.getChars(ReplacementTransformationMethod.java:151)
                                                             at android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:70)
                                                             at android.text.TextUtils.indexOf(TextUtils.java:103)
                                                             at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:182)
                                                             at android.text.DynamicLayout.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:284)
                                                             at android.text.DynamicLayout.<init>(DynamicLayout.java:170)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.makeSingleLayout(TextView.java:5843)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:5741)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6280)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3547)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3405)
                                                             at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3380)
                                                             at kz.tem_tour.Booking.Mask$1.onTextChanged(Mask.java:40)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7079)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3550)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3405)
                                                             at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3380)
                                                             at kz.tem_tour.Booking.Mask$1.onTextChanged(Mask.java:40)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7079)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3550)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3405)
                                                             at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3380)
                                                             at kz.tem_tour.Booking.Mask$1.onTextChanged(Mask.java:40)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7079)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3550)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3405)
                                                             at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3380)
                                                             at kz.tem_tour.Booking.Mask$1.onTextChanged(Mask.java:40)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7079)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3550)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3405)
                                                             at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3380)
                                                             at kz.tem_tour.Booking.Mask$1.onTextChanged(Mask.java:40)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7079)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3550)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3405)
                                                             at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3380)
                                                             at kz.tem_tour.Booking.Mask$1.onTextChanged(Mask.java:40)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7079)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3550)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3405)
                                                             at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3380)
                                                             at kz.tem_tour.Booking.Mask$1.onTextChanged(Mask.java:40)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7079)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3550)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3405)
                                                             at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3380)
                                                             at kz.tem_tour.Booking.Mask$1.onTextChanged(Mask.java:40)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7079)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3550)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3405)
                                                             at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3380)
                                                             at kz.tem_tour.Booking.Mask$1.onTextChanged(Mask.java:40)
                                                             at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7079)
                                                            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView
```

Подскажите, что неправильно делаю?

Comment: метод `setText` вызыает `onTextChanged`, который вызывает `setText`, который вызывает `onTextChanged`, который вызывает `setText`, который вызывает `onTextChanged`, который вызывает `setText`, который вызывает `onTextChanged`...

Comment: Не очень понял(

Answer (score 2):

Даже не знаю, как понятнее объяснить...
Метод `ediTxt.setText(mascara);` вызывает у `TextWatcher` метод `onTextChanged`, оповещая текствотчер о том, что текст изменился. Внутри метода `onTextChanged` вы опять меняете текст, вызывая метод `ediTxt.setText(mascara);`, что опять же вызывает метод `onTextChanged`. И так до бесконечности. Точнее, до переполнения стека.

Comment: Как можно устранить подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: Просто Маска работает если EditText не в Массиве, а обычнм способом, например Просто вызвать таким образом, editText.addTextChangedListener(Mask.insert("##.##.####", ListBirthDate.get(i)));